# OS-update in VMWare "Template VM" - possible to propagate to the LINK:ed VM:s?

Tags: windows-10, updates, vmware-workstation, clone

*OS-update in VMWare "Template VM" - possible to propagate to the LINK:ed VM:s?*

To elaborate; using VMware Workstation 15 Pro I have a Windows 10 "Template" from which I have created LINKED clones. These are to sandbox various categories of software, depending on provider and type (e.g. different installation **variations** of Siemens STEP7 to begin with).

Now I see Windows 10 21H2 rolling in, and in the naïve way; that means doing the longish update in each VM separately.

**So; IS there another means to have these VM guest OS updates e.g. automatically(?) propagate from an update of the template to the (linked) clones?**

I have been googling and searching the VMWare help and see some kind of INDICATION (vSphere?!, Replication!?) that it should be possible; but no clear and concise step through - nor anything in VMWare menus or options.

*I have a sense of "Running around in circles!"...*
*(shame on you VMWare! Revise your documentation to be more specific!)*

Comment: Linked clones are created from a snapshot--an *exact* point in the life of the VM.  Snapshots are immutable.  It is not possible to propagate additional changes to the template VM to existing linked clones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic stays at a level below this;

Templates - as many other things - are STATIC.
A changed Template is still just a template, in a new state.

What was created (earlier) from the template does not follow into the new state.